# How to install C/C++-Extension in VSCode-Server?

Tags: c++, code-server

I have set up a code-server on a remote machine and when browsing the extensions, the C/C++-Extension from Microsoft is not available. 
It is also not possible to install it via the CLI:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ code-server --install-extension ms-vscode.cpptools
Installing extensions...
Extension 'ms-vscode.cpptools' not found.
Make sure you use the full extension ID, including the publisher, e.g.: ms-dotnettools.csharp
Failed Installing Extensions: ms-vscode.cpptools
```

Is this extension just not available, or is it, because the server is not accessible via HTTPS (I couldn't get the certification to work)

Answer (score 3):

First you have to fullfill prerequisites: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux

Then download the extension:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools

-> Click on version history and choose for your linux architecture.

Install extension with: `code-server --install-extension ms-vscode.cpptools-1.10.3@linux-x64.vsix`

Comment: Do you have a way to install this programmatically without attended clicks?

Comment: Should be possible if you write a script, but haven't tried it, since I didn't need it.

Comment: It kind of works, but vscode CLI does not seem to have a fully consistent behavior.
I have opened a couple of trackers with the involved teams:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/discussions/11154#discussioncomment-6387284

and one here that is not yet published:

https://github.com/coder/code-server/issues